# I have apache2 installed and working and now trying to get python code to work

Tags: python, html, apache, webserver

Is it possible to some convert my python code so its able to run through html so i can run it through my web server? I have tried writing the code "<%(code inside of here) %>" but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: What system are you on? Ubuntu? Have you installed the Python and dependencies?

Comment: im on linux and yes i have @M.Foldager

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need the WSGI extension for apache in order to run python code:

https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html